# Request two or more url parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I passing two url paramters to a different div but cant seem to get it to work, the second parameter in the script below bring out the first url parameter again. the alert bring out `CID : url parameter "user_id" + url parameter "user_id"` instead of `url parameter "user_id" + url parameter "username"`

```
<script>
$("#page2").live("pageshow", function onPageShow(e,data){

    alert('Page 2 - CID: ' + getParameterByName('user_id') + getParameterByName('username') );
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));


}     
    </script>
```

Comment: aside: why would you name the function passed to live(onPageShow)?

Comment: I'm new in jquery so i got a script from the web and i tried editting it

Comment: that's not about jquery, it is just javascript. it doesn't make any sense to name the function there, use an anonymous one ;)

Comment: $("#page2").live("pageshow", function(e,data){...});

Comment: can you phrase it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns the value of the parameter that you are asking for:

e.g `getParameterByName('user_id')` will return the value of the user_id URL(GET) variable

Here is a testrun in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/xca8mbq3/3/).